# How to smoothen edges in Helix Toolkit SharpDX viewport?

Tags: rendering, antialiasing, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

So I recently migrated a project from the native helix-toolkit library to the helix-toolkit sharpDX branch and noted that the edges of my models seem to be more [jiggly/step-like](http://ni.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/23874i923C9AF031B29657?v=v2) than before.

I tried to find something to manipulate smoothness or anti aliasing, but couldn't find anything.

Looking through the examples of the helixtool-kit sharpDX source code, I noted that in the [DeferredShadingDemo](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/master/Source/Examples/WPF.SharpDX/DeferredShadingDemo) the edges seemed to be smoother.

I tried to use the deferred rendering in my example, but ran into problems.
Before perusing this solution though, I thought I could ask you for a possible easier, more legit solution to my problem.

Thanks already!

Comment: For now I went with the deferred rendering solution and the model looks way nicer. I had to do two things to get the Deferred Renderer running in my example: 1. Turn of shadowmapping 2. Include the Texture Folder from the example in the helix toolkit source code. I checked the wiki for deferred rendering and it should not be connected with better antialiasing ( seems to be connected with a more efficient lighting of the scene) I don't know why it is working it just did the trick for me. Maybe someone can share some wisdom ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice solution posted by BetaRavener on the helixtoolkit github.
Check out the link for a description: 
https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/issues/311